# Deploying Ant-generated jar to Nexus using maven-deploy-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a multi-module project with war and ear module. In war's pom I'm generating jar using maven-antrun-plugin. Now I'm trying to deploy that jar to my Nexus using maven-deploy-plugin.

Here's my war's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>test-war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>

<!-- <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <url><nexus_releases_repo_url></url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url><nexus_snapshots_repo_url></url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement> -->

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ant-build</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <ant antfile="<path_to_build_xml>" target="run" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-file</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <repositoryId>nexus-snapshots</repositoryId>
                        <file>fileToDeploy.jar</file>
                        <url>http://<path_to_my_repo></url>
                        <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}-tmp</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `clean deploy` on parent pom, I'm getting the following error:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]`

Ok, so I've added `distributionManagement` section in war's pom, but I'm getting the same error. If I run the same command on war module, there's no error, but there's also war file deployed on Nexus next to jar file.

Is there a way to deploy just jar file using `deploy` command?

Comment: Can you check whether you have the entry for the repository under Server tag in settings.xml and if yes, if the id match with what is in the pom.xml?

Comment: @Anitha.R Yes, id match with settings.xml entry.